# "error": "Method Not Allowed" in postman, springboot old project

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I have created springboot code in my old project, which was working one week ago but now I am unable to run it. When I am sending this Post request :- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/122?name=shre12` in Postman I am getting this error:-

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-07-09T01:42:56.979+00:00",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "path": "/user/122"
}
```

Controller.kt:-

```
@RestController
class Controller(private var userService: UserService) {

    @PostMapping("/user/{id}")
    fun newStudent(
        @PathVariable id: String,
        @RequestParam("name") name: String
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return try {
            val userResponse = JSONObject()
            val user = UserDocument(id, name)
            userResponse.put("addUser", user)

            val userSignUp = UserDocument(id, name)
            userService.addUser(userSignUp)

            ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.FOUND)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(userSignUp.toString())
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            ResponseEntity(e.message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
}
```

Model.kt:-

```
@Document(collection = "usersData")
data class UserDocument(
    @Id
    val id: String? = null,
    val name: String
)
```

Repository.kt:-

```
interface UserRepository : MongoRepository<UserDocument?, Int?> {}
```

Service.kt :-

```
@Service
class UserService(private val userRepository: UserRepository) {

    fun addUser(user: UserDocument) {
        val processedUser = user.copy(
            id = user.id,
            name = user.name
        )
        userRepository.save(processedUser)
    }
```

}

But in the fresh project if I am using the same code it is working. I don't know what is wrong with the old project?

I have already rebuild the project and Invalidate caches and restarted the Ide but still it is giving me the same error.

**Note:- I am using Kotlin instead of java and build.gradle.kts instead of maven**

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the path as `"path": "/login/122"` not `"/user/{id}"`

if you mistakenly put the `user` as `login` then try,

```
@RestController
class Controller(private var userService: UserService) {

    @RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.POST])
    fun newStudent(
        @PathVariable id: String,
        @RequestParam("name") name: String
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return try {
            val userResponse = JSONObject()
            val user = UserDocument(id, name)
            userResponse.put("addUser", user)

            val userSignUp = UserDocument(id, name)
            userService.addUser(userSignUp)

            ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(userSignUp.toString())
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            ResponseEntity(e.message, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The response was of another method by mistake I put it here. In the original project there are lots of methods I posted here only one by commenting all the other code. I have updated the question, the problem is with something else. I tried your answer but it is not working.  The same code is working in new project.